# cannot convert (type string) to type errorString

Tags: go, error-handling

I wrote a simple program which does executing uptime command and fetch its result. As part of error handling I am getting trouble while converting error type into string and string type to error. How can I achieve this ?

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os/exec"
)

type errorString struct {
    s string
  }

func (e *errorString) Error() string {
  return e.s
}

func execCommand(cmd string) (string, error) {
  if cmd == "" {
    return "", &errorString("Passed empty input")
  }

  output, err := exec.Command(cmd).Output()
  fmt.Println("Output: " ,string(output))
  fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Received error %q while executing the command %q", err, cmd)
    return "",err
  }
  fmt.Printf("Command executed successfully.\nOutput: %s\n",output)
  return string(output), nil
}

func main() {

  command := "uptime"
  output, err := execCommand(command)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf("Received error while executing the command\n")
  } else {
    fmt.Printf("Command %s output %s ", command, output)
  }
}
```

And while executing getting below error

```sh
agastya in uptime_cmd on   my-code-go
❯  go run execute_uptime_command_1.go
# command-line-arguments
./execute_uptime_command_1.go:18:28: cannot convert "Passed empty input" (type string) to type errorString
agastya in uptime_cmd on   my-code-go
```

What I am trying to achieve is, trying to convert a string into error and vice versa. I am trying to implement below test cases to above code

```golang
package main
import (
  "testing"
  "strings"
)

func TestExecCommand(t *testing.T) {

  command := "uptime"
  expectedIncludes := "load"
  received, err := execCommand(command)
  if !strings.Contains(received, expectedIncludes) {
    t.Errorf("Expecting %q to include %q", received, expectedIncludes)
  }

  received, err = execCommand("")
  if received != "" {
    t.Errorf("Expecting empty response when command is empty")
  }

  received, err = execCommand("uptime1")
  if !strings.Contains(string(err), "executable file not found in $PATH") {
    t.Errorf("Expecting executable not found error while executing invalid command as 'uptime1'");
  }
}
```

And Unable to proceed with above error. Any suggestions much appreicated. It dont have to be explicit solution, even reference articles are fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an error from string use

```
return "", &errorString{"Passed empty input"}
```